# User clicks too fast bug

Tags: javascript

first of all i'm pretty new to JS.
i'm trying to make a memory game but i have the next problem.
the code :

```
function cardClicked(elCard) {
  // If the user clicked an already flipped card - do nothing and return from the function
  if (elCard.classList.contains('flipped')) {
    return;
  }
  // Flip it
  elCard.classList.add('flipped');

  // This is a first card, only keep it in the global variable
  if (elPreviousCard === null) {
    elPreviousCard = elCard;

  } else {
    // get the data-card attribute's value from both cards
    var card1 = elPreviousCard.getAttribute('data-card');
    var card2 = elCard.getAttribute('data-card');
    // No match, schedule to flip them back in 1 second
    if (card1 !== card2) {

        setTimeout(function () {
            elCard.classList.remove('flipped');
            elPreviousCard.classList.remove('flipped');
            elPreviousCard = null;
        }, 1000)
        wrongPick.play();
    } else {
        // Yes! a match!
        flippedCouplesCount++;
        elPreviousCard = null;
        rightPick.play();
    }
}
```

---

i would like to prevent the user from clicking more then two times (it's a memory game.) can someone tell me how can i implement this into my code please?

Comment: Have you tried preventing the user from clicking twice? What did you try?

Comment: By saying preventing the user from clicking twice i mean clicking on more then 2 cards. (the game goes like that -> you pick a card -> then you pick another card. -> if its a match the cards stays. if not cards fade after 10sec.

Comment: Can you explain a little better? What scenario are you trying to prevent? Is it when a user has already picked one card, then he immediately picks the second, and a third, or just picking two cards in a small timeframe? What interval should there be between clicks?

Comment: The senario i'm trying to prevent is fast clicking. if the user clicks on 3 cards (quick). he can bug the code. Or prevent the code from giving a delay (the 10 sec delay). But what im trying to achive is after the user clicking 2 times maybe lock all the other cards. until the cards go back to default..

Answer (score 0):

You can set a global variable to isClickable initially set to true, enter the code check if its true, if it isn't, return, else go ahead and set it to false and do a timeout to set it to true again, like:

```
var isClickable = true;
function cardClicked(elCard) {
  if (!isClickable) return;
  isClickable = false;
  setTimeout(function () {
    isClickable = true;
  }, 500)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a card game I would do the following:
Make array of elements:

```
var cards = (
    {
     "card":"numberOfCard",
     "isclicked" :"yes/no"
    }
);
```

And then every time somebody clicks on card I would change isClickable to no so next time event occures I would prevent it.

Answer (score 0):

create variable for example `opened_cards` that store how many card opened, if less than 2 allow open another card else do nothing.

```
var opened_cards = 0;

function cardClicked(elCard) {
  // do check here
  if (opened_cards < 2) {
    // less than 2 card opened do operation 
    opened_cards++;
    if (elCard.classList.contains('flipped')) {
      return;
    }
    // Flip it
    elCard.classList.add('flipped');

    // This is a first card, only keep it in the global variable
    if (elPreviousCard === null) {
      elPreviousCard = elCard;

    }
    else {
      // get the data-card attribute's value from both cards
      var card1 = elPreviousCard.getAttribute('data-card');
      var card2 = elCard.getAttribute('data-card');
      // No match, schedule to flip them back in 1 second
      if (card1 !== card2) {

        setTimeout(function() {
          opened_cards -= 2;
          elCard.classList.remove('flipped');
          elPreviousCard.classList.remove('flipped');
          elPreviousCard = null;
        }, 1000);
        wrongPick.play();
      }
      else {
        // Yes! a match!
        opened_cards = 0;
        flippedCouplesCount++;
        elPreviousCard = null;
        rightPick.play();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You should probably put your opened_cards++ after the flipped check